# Using ZIPFoundation Library in e-commerce app, do I have to copy the license and add inside the code?

Tags: licensing

I am using the first time the open-source library. I have to export some files of costumer as a ZIP, seems the ZIPFoundation looks great to use it. I read the license which wrote it is free, but the line which wrote:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

It means I have to add in code or I have to show alert to end user when using zip, that copy right belong to this person (seems strange but I want to be sure :) )

Answer (score 2):

That is not strange at all. It is a requirement of basically every license that authorship is acknowledged. Open source does not mean 'free to use without any obligation'.

Thus the right thing to do is to display in the 'about' tab, the readme or on the same place you show your copyright also the copyright notices of 3rd party software used - like this licenses information.

This does not mean you have to spring a separate pop - up into your users face when they save to zip.